# A slightly different version of the halting problemo

Tags: algorithm, theory, halting-problem

I got stuck with a question and would like to have a little guidance for the solution.

I need to prove that the next problem is undecidable:
**Input** - A program
**Problem** - Does the number of possible inputs for which the program halts is larger than those for which the program won't halt?

I tried to build a reduction that (in case the input is even) halts for every even number, goes to an infinite loop for every odd and runs the program with the input. Or in case the input is odd does the opposite - but it only works if I am able to prove that the number of real odd numbers is equal to the real even numbers.

Comment: The usual way is to construct another program that can use this one to solve the halting problem. If you succeed, you've proven that the original program can't exist.

Comment: @sascha Not for me, sadly. I tried to build one that (in case the input is even) halts for every even number, goes to an infinite loop for every odd and runs the program with the input. Or in case the input is odd does the opposite - but it only works if I am able to prove that the number of real odd numbers is equal to the real even numbers.

Comment: @biziclop That was my approach too, but I wasn't able to come up with a good one.

Comment: @biziclop Could you think of a general discription for a program that could help me?

Comment: @Eddie you could consider the problem of solving the halting program for programs that completely ignore their input. You might also consider writing a program that ignores the provided input, but writes out data which a second program treats as if it was input, so the combination of the two completely ignores the original input, but the second program treats the output of the first as if it was input.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint.

˙„ɥƃnouǝ ǝƃɹɐʃ„ ǝɹɐ ʇɐɥʇ sʇnduı ʃʃɐ ɹoɟ ʇʃɐɥ ʇɥƃıɯ ʇɐɥʇ sɯɐɹƃoɹd ʇɐ ʞoo˥